# Linked columns in an Excel document

Tags: excel, reference

I'm trying to create an excel document with two sheets, the first one containing a list of fruit types, for example

```
ID Description 
1 Apple 
2 Orange 
3 Pear
...
```

The second sheet would contain a reference to a row from the first sheet and some additional data.
For example

```
Fruit_ID Quantity Customer
1 12 Chris 
3 7 Jenny 
...
```

And when a user is adding a new row in the second sheet he would be presented with a drop down list of entries from the second sheet when setting the first column value.
The number of rows in the second sheet is dynamic ( user will be adding data into it).

How can I do this ?

Comment: Possibly with a combination of a `LOOKUP` formula and, for the dropdown, `Data Validation`.  When you've worked something up, if you have problems, post back. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells where you want to display dropdown.

Go to Data Tab > Data Validation
 Enter the following criteria

- Allow:List
- Source: =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,1,0,COUNT(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$1048576))

Change the sheet name accordingly and it will show drop-down based on the Sheet1, column 1.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Couldn't do it. I've selected a column on the second sheet, went to Data validation and tried to enter the (correctly modified) =OFFSET(..., but all I got was a "There's a problem with this formula" .... Will try again on a different version of Excel.

Comment: if you are using old excel version (file extension .xls) try changing the range as `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,1,0,COUNT(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$65000))`